# How do you nunit TestFixture in same cs file as project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

In class they taught us to add a test fixture to the same namespace as the project we're testing. For example:

```
namespace Project
{
    class Decrypt : Cipher
    {
        public string Execute()
        {
            //Code here
        }
    }
    [TestFixture]
    {
        [Test]
        public void test1()
        {
            //Code here
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed in the c# menu on my uni computer, there was a 'Test' section (I couldn't get it to run there either, I don't know how). On this old 32b computer there isn't. I've installed NUnit-2.6.2.msi but when I try to run it, it says "Unable to find a version of runtime to run this application"
So I think I have two problems:

- installing Nunit (I already have referenced the .dlls from my project separately)
- using Nunit (even on a computer with it installed properly)

Comment: I do not put my tests in the same file or project as the code to test. If you use resharper it has nice integration for running tests. I dont know id VS will run Nunit tests but I guess it will.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'd put your code in separate projects, but reference the project you're testing in the test project

```
//project: Xarian.Security
//file: Decrypt.cs
namespace Xarian.Security
{
    class Decrypt : Cipher
    {
        public string Execute()
        {
            //Code here
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
//project: Xarian.Security.Test
//file: DecryptTest.cs

using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
//as we're already in the Xarian.Security namespace, no need 
//to reference it in code.  However the DLL needs to be referenced 
//(Solution Explorer, Xarian.Security.Test, References, right click, 
//Add Reference, Projects, Xarian.Security)

namespace Xarian.Security
{
    [TestFixture]
    class DecryptTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void test()
        {
            //Code here
            Cipher cipher = new Decrypt("&^%&^&*&*()%%&**&&^%$^&$%^*^%&*(");
            string result = cipher.Execute();
            Assert.AreEqual(string, "I'm Decrypted Successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

Right click on the test project's references, go to the Projects tab and select the main project.  Once referenced you'll be able to use the classes (etc) from your main project in your test code.